# How to set up a running environment on Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables

I want to customize a command to set up running environment, but I'm having some issue here. For example, I can run:

```
envsetup
```

and it will run the following script to help set up the environment:

```
cd /opt/dir/set_up | source environment
```

I have tried to add the following code to my $HOME .bashrc file, but it's not working (Maybe I should add it to the .bashrc in my root dir?):

```
alias envsetup = 'cd /opt/dir/set_up | source environment'
```

Could anyone let me know what might be wrong here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

- The `cd` command changes directories and doesn't output anything to
  standard output (`stdout`). So there's no point in piping its output to another command with `|`. If you want to execute two commands in sequence, you can separate with `;`.
- When defining an `alias` you can't be too generous
  with spaces.

Here's an option, then, to do what I think you want:

```
alias envsetup='cd /opt/dir/set_up ; source environment'
```

---

Per additional desire expressed in the comment, if you want to come back to the original directory, you can do it this way:

```
alias envsetup='(cd /opt/dir/set_up ; source environment)'
```

This runs the commands in a subshell so your current shell setup is unchanged, including the current working directory.

Note that since this runs in a subshell, if `source` is intended to change the environment variables in a persistent way, then this will not work. You can, alternatively, try something like this:

```
alias envsetup='p=$(pwd) ; cd /opt/dir/set_up ; source environment ; cd $p'
```

This will run in the same shell. You can choose whatever name you wish for `p`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked! Just one more follow up. When I run `envsetup` it took me to the `/opt/dir/set_up` but I'd like to stay in my current directory to do more stuff after setting up the environment. Is there any suggestion regarding to how can I do that?

Comment: @ImTrying great, glad it did what you wanted! Perhaps you could accept the answer if that's the case. Regarding you're follow-up question: *When I run envsetup it took me to the /opt/dir/set_up but I'd like to stay in my current directory...* it's a little unclear what you mean here. You wanted it initially to take you to the new directory, but you want now to stay where you are. Exactly what do you need it to do overall? Does it need to go to the new directory, run the script, then come back? See my edit,  assuming I guessed right. :)

Comment: Simpler would be `source /opt/dir/set_up/environment`

Comment: @stark I don't know what the OP's script does and whether it requires to be in that working directory to perform certain functions. So that suggestion may or may not work as expected.

Comment: It will work better than trying to change environment variables in a subshell

Comment: @stark it's not guaranteed to work at all is what I'm saying. It depends upon what that script does. Changing current directory in a subshell is not uncommon.

Comment: Do you not know that the changes to the environment are lost when you exit the subshell?

Comment: @stark of course I know. In this case, unless the `source` script is changing environment variables in a persistent way, this should not be an issue. I suppose there could be a small risk that it is doing so. But my assumption is that the OP isn't relying on the `source` script changing the environment variables in a persistent way.

Comment: Title:  "How to set up a running environment on Ubuntu?"

Comment: @stark - I think the OP is using the word "environment" loosely. It doesn't say that he's looking for persistent environment variable changes, but I understand your point. Since the OP accepted the answer, I assume that is the case. I updated the answer to include the case where persistent environment variables are expected.

Comment: @stark It's also possible that `environment` is a not subfolder in `/opt/dir/set_up`. It might just be a script argument. The original question doesn't say.